# Retrieve password from kerberos keytab file

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, hue, keytab

I am using hadoop with kerberos keytab file name **userid.keytab** for a long while. But now i m not aware the password. Is it anyway to get password from the keytab file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't. 
The only thing you can get from a keytab file is the principal name:

```
$ ktutil 
ktutil:  read_kt test.wtk 
ktutil:  list 
slot KVNO Principal
---- ---- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    1                hadoop_app@BLALBLABLA.LOC
```

Keytab contains pairs of principal and 
encrypted keys (which are derived from the Kerberos password), no way to get back the password from these data.

Answer (score 0):

Keytab has a principal name at the very least, but can also hold the NTLM hash of the password, next to AES hashes of the same password.

Extract hashes with https://github.com/sosdave/KeyTabExtract